# Lagrange multiplier

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold. Let $E(u)=\displaystyle\int_MuP(u) dV_g$, where $P$ is a linear self-adjoint operator, and $dV_g$ is the volume form with respect to $g$. Given a smooth function $k$ which takes both positive and negative values, let 
$$F=\{u: \int_Mu dV_g=0\mbox{ and } \int_M ke^{4u}dV_g=0\}.$$

Suppose $u\in F$ is a minimizer: $E(u)=\min_{v\in F}E(v)$. The paper I am reading claimed that by the theory of Lagrange multiplier, we have 
$$P(u)=\alpha +\beta ke^{4u}$$
for some $\alpha, \beta\in \mathbb{R}$. I don't understand how to derive it. Could anyone give me some help? Thank you very much.

Comment: I assume that should be $\int_M ke^{4u}dV_g=0$ and not $\int_M ke^{4v}dV_g=0$ in definition of $F$?

Comment: @Rahul: Yes. That's a typo. I changed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you need also to assume that $\int u \mathrm{d}V_g$ and $\int k e^{4u}\mathrm{d} V_g$ are $C^1$ functionals on your function space.

Then: let $\mathcal{H}$ be a real Hilbert space. Let $S, K_1, K_2$ be $C^1$ functionals such that $K_1$ and $K_2$ intersect transversely, then the set $\mathcal{N} = \{K_1 = k_1\}\cap\{K_2 = k_2\}$ is a $C^1$ Hilbert manifold, and we can apply the [theory of Lagrange Multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multipliers_on_Banach_spaces) as follows: if $u\in \mathcal{N}$ is a constrained critical point of $S$, we must have $DS(u) = \lambda_1 DK_1(u) + \lambda_2 DK_2(u)$ where $D$ is the Frechet derivative on $\mathcal{H}$.

Applying to the calculus of variations, you have that Frechet derivatives $DS(u):\mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfy the Gateaux differentiation condition
$$ DS(u) \cdot h = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t}[ S(u+th) - S(u)] $$
which using calculus of variations and applying to your case where $\mathcal{H} = L^2(M,\mathrm{d}V_g)$ with $\langle f,g\rangle = \int fg \mathrm{d}V_g$, and $S$ is the energy functional, $K_1$ and $K_2$ are the given constraints gives
$$ DS[u] \cdot h = \int h P(u) + u P(h) \mathrm{d}V_g $$
where using that $P$ is self-adjoint gives you
$$ = \int 2h P(u) \mathrm{d}V_g ~.$$
Similarly you get
$$ DK_1[u] \cdot h = \int h \mathrm{d}V_g $$
and
$$ DK_2[u] \cdot h = \int 4 k e^{4u} h \mathrm{d}V_g~. $$

Putting this together tells you that for a constrained critical point of $S$ under constraints $K_1,K_2$, the solution $u$ must satisfies that for all $h\in\mathcal{H}$

$$ \int h\left( 2P(u) - \lambda_1 - 4\lambda_2k e^{4u}\right) \mathrm{d}V_g = 0$$

and hence the term inside the parentheses must be 0.

---

For the case in the paper you are reading, some further justification probably is involved. (For example, you hadn't told us on *what* function space is $P$ a self-adjoint operator).) If it is $L^2$ as I inferred, $\int ke^{4u}\mathrm{d}V_g$ is not actually $C^1$ (it is not even bounded). Nevertheless, one can usually apply some renormalisation to replace $K_2$ by another functional that is identical to $K_2$ when $|K_2[u]|\leq \epsilon$ and suitably cut-off outside. Slightly more worrisome is that $P$ is likely to be only densely defined on $L^2$ for most geometric applications, which throws some more caveats into the above.

But on a formal level, the above derivation (and more simply speaking, Rahul's answer) explains what you seek.

Comment: btw, for $K_1$ in my notation to be continuous (and hence $C^1$), it is necessary and sufficient that $M$ has finite total volume.

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote the inner product $\int_M uv\ \mathrm{d}V_g$ by $\langle u,v \rangle$. We want to minimize $E(u) = \langle u,Pu \rangle$ subject to $\langle u,1 \rangle = 0$ and $\langle k,e^{4u} \rangle = 0$.

I'm no expert on Riemannian manifolds or functional analysis, so I don't know if this is the right terminology, but: what I'd call the "gradients" of the objective and constraint functions are $2Pu$, $1$, and $4ke^{4u}$ respectively. In the sense that if you consider a small variation $\delta u$ in $u$, the change in $E(u)$ to first order is $\langle \delta u, 2Pu \rangle$, and so on.

Then by Lagrange multipliers, we immediately find that the solution must satisfy $2Pu + \lambda \cdot 1 + \mu \cdot 4ke^{4u} = 0$. This is equivalent to your desired result.